# Android - what is the real use of - category

Tags: android

I am quite new to Android

I studied how to use category (in the intent-filter). And I know category is used for grouping the activities. But didn't understand what is the real use of - category.

Can any help me in this regard - **siting the practical use of category**.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The category gives additional information about the action to execute. For example, [CATEGORY_LAUNCHER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_LAUNCHER) means it should appear in the Launcher as a top-level application, while [CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE) means it should be included in a list of alternative actions the user can perform on a piece of data.

[Here is a full list of categories with a short description](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_DEFAULT)

Comment: Sorry. May be because I am just a beginner I couldn't get it. As far as I know - the app start with an Activity & it then navigates through different activities (or just call & come back to the present activity). Here - what difference it makes if it marked with some label - LAUNCHER or ALTERNATIVE. How actually it comes into play?

Comment: CATEGORY_LAUNCHER is that the activity is available in the app list in the launcher, while CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE is for example for launching an activity for spezific DATA, for example the youtube app. if you click on a youtube link android asks you if you want to open the link in your browser, or in the youtube app (it also provides an checkbox to always open youtube links with the selected app) [here](http://mobileorchard.com/android-app-development-menus-part-3-alternative-menus/) you can find a sample for how to use the CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE